# A question concerning measurability of a function

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, functions, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded and let $X:=H^1(\Omega)$. Let $a:\Omega\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, (x,z)\mapsto a(x,z)$ be a bounded function such that $a(x,.)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ for every $x$ and $a(.,z)$ is measurable on $\Omega$ for every $z$.

For $v,\phi\in H^1$ one finds in pde the integral
$$\int_\Omega a(x,v(x))\nabla v(x) \cdot \nabla\phi(x) dx$$
All measures should be the Lebesgue measure
My question is: Why is $a(x,v(x))$ a measurable function, why is $a(x,z)$ measurable on $\Omega\times \mathbb{R}$ or why is the integral defined?

Usually one can not conclude from measurability of each compontent to measurability on the product space. Somehow i feel I need more measure theory than i know yet :)

Comment: Functions measurable in one coordinate and continuous in the other are [Caratheodory functions](http://books.google.at/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=%22caratheodory+function%22+jointly+measurable&source=bl&ots=p9rQVsm_Kx&sig=o18wOwrz_27m0HCdPJUJNsmLQc4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wQ9DUY-DMpLo7AbdmoDYDw&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22caratheodory%20function%22%20jointly%20measurable&f=false) and they are jointly measurable.

Comment: thanks, that solves my problem :) Didn't know the name of such functions.

Comment: @Michael: can you post that as an answer?

Comment: In a different setting one requires the measurability of $a(x,v)$ where $v \in X:=L^\infty([0,1])$, $a$ still bounded. But $X$ is not separable which was required in your link. Or could one exploit that each such $v$ is in fact in $L^2((0,1))$ and this space is separable? (The integral would then be with $\nabla w$ instead of $\nabla w$ for some $w\in H^1$ (eg for stationary porous medium equation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions measurable in one coordinate and continuous in the other are Caratheodory functions and they are jointly measurable. This is [Lemma 4.51](http://books.google.at/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&dq=%22caratheodory%20function%22%20jointly%20measurable&source=bl&ots=p9rQVsm_Kx&sig=o18wOwrz_27m0HCdPJUJNsmLQc4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wQ9DUY-DMpLo7AbdmoDYDw&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22caratheodory%20function%22%20jointly%20measurable&f=false) in *Infinite Dimensional Analysis (3rd Ed)* by Aliprantis and Border.

Comment: Thanks very much. I have one question on that, assume $v(x)\in L^\infty$ (or just a measurable function) then by that theorem it is not clear why the composition $a(x,v(x))$ is a measurable function. The Theorem only states that $a(x,z)$ is measurable. Is such a composition of measurable functions again measurable? (Rudin defines measurability via the preimage of open sets is measurable). So there should be some work left to do?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 Compositions of measurable functions are measurable, but to see that, you need [a more general notion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function#Formal_definition) of measurability. Rudins notion reduces to the case in which the codomain is endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. It would probably help if you would familiarize yourself with product $\sigma$-algebras. The chapter on easurability in Aliprantis & Border is probably a good starting point

Comment: I should be more precise: I know that the composition of measurable functions is again measurable. I searched here also for the compositon on measurable functions and one remark found here [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function) says that the compostion of Lebesgue-measurable functions need not to be measurable again, due to the change of the $\sigma$-algebras (as you also mentioned). But since I want to integrate with respect to Lebesgue I need more Lebesgue-measurability of $a(x,v(x))$. This is not covered by the theorem you mentioned, right? Or am i totallty mistaken?

Comment: For every Lebesgue measurable function, there is a Borel measurable function that agrees with it almost everywhere. Every Borel-measurable function is also Lebesgue measurable, so you can intgrate them all the same. And for composing, the work much nicr.

Comment: Okay, thanks very much. Additionally, I think I found a different solution without using such properties of Lebesgue measurable functions. I think I will post it tomorrow if no one else will do this :)

Comment: Hey Michael, I hope you still reas this. I just reconsidered this here. Does Lemma 4.49 also help? The function $h(x):=(x,v(x))$ maps into then the first component maps Lebesgue measurable sets into L-meas sets (since it is Lipschitz), is a standard Lebesgue measurable function (in rudins sense). Application of Lemma 4.51 yields that $g(h(x)) :\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue, measurable. Is this correct?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 What is $g$?

Comment: sorry, $g$ should be $a$. Summarizing, this should be $a(x,v(x))=a(h(x))$. And for $h$ we can apply lemma 4.49 and use that $x$ is Lipschitz, and for $a$ we use lemma 4.51, right?

Comment: The identity function is trivially measurable. The rest should work.

Comment: If course, it is measurable, In my mind I'm also interested in $v(x,t)$ and in particular $a(x,v(x,t))$. Then $(x,t)\mapsto x$ is still Lipschitz (but otherwise measurability should also be immediate). Nevertheless, thanks again for your comment

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I found a more direct approach sufficient to my needs. Whenever, I refer to measurable I mean Lebesgue-measurable on the Lebesgue-measurable set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $a:\Omega\times\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Caratheodory-function, i.e. $a(x,z)$ is measurable in $x$ for every $z$ and continuous in $z$ for every $x$.

Let $v:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Then $a(x,v(x))$ is mearuable.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Since $v$ is measurable the exists a simple function $v_k(x)=\sum_{j=0}^k \lambda_j \chi_j(x)\to v(x)$ for every $x$ and with $\lambda_j \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\chi_j$ appropriate characteristic funtions of disjoint measurable sets $E_j$. We assume $\lambda_0=0$ and $E_0=[\cup_{j=1}^n E_j]^C$.

We will show that $a(x,u_k(x))$ is measurable. To this end, we show that $\{x:a(x,u_k(x))>t\}$ is measurable. There holds:

$$\{x:a(x,u_k(x))>t\}=\bigcup_{j=0}^{n}(\{x:a(x,\lambda_j)>t\}\cap E_j)$$
Since $E_j$ is measurable, and $\{x:a(x,\lambda_j)>t\}$ is measurable due to the assumptions we find the assertion.

It remains to pass to the limit $u_k \to u$.

Thanks to the continuity of $a$ in the second argument we find
$a(x,u_k(x))\to a(x,u(x))$ for every $x$. On the left hand side we find a measurable function and due to the pointwise limit of measurable functions being measruable again we conclude.

Hope this is error free :)