# Lebesgue measurable function

Tags: lebesgue-measure

I'm reading an article and have to use the following statement.

If $g$ is a real valued function on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that $g_{x}$ is Lebesgue measurable for all $x \in E$  and $g^{y}$ is continuos for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$ then $g$ is Lebesgue measurable.

Is it true? Does anyone know why?
I tried to justify and could not.

Comment: An idea for a place to start: given an open set $U$ in $\mathbb{R}$, notice that $\bigcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} g_q^{-1}(U)$ is measurable, because it is a countable union of measurable sets. The same is true for the other section (continuity implies measurability). Can you somehow relate $g^{-1}(U)$ back to one of these sets?

Comment: Could you link the article? Could you explain the notation ($g_x$? $E$?)?

Comment: @Craneviter Please look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647235/counterexample-to-measurable-in-each-variable-separately-implies-measurable

Comment: You can also have a look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/331281/75808) in a related Math.SE question. It gives a reference for a proof of your question ([Lemma 4.51 of *Infinite Dimensional Analysis* (3rd Ed.), Aliprantis and Border](https://books.google.at/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA153&lpg=PA153&source=bl&ots=p9rQVsm_Kx&sig=o18wOwrz_27m0HCdPJUJNsmLQc4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=wQ9DUY-DMpLo7AbdmoDYDw#v=onepage&q&f=false)).